# How to pass an argument to Bash fucntion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a simple code, where I try to pass arguments in for to another function and get result.
I run `./my_script.sh 1 2 3 4`

```
#!/bin/bash
function multi {
    local ax=$1
    local result=$(($ax + $ax))
    return $result
}

function f {
    local arg="$@"
    for i in ${arg[@]}; do
        RES=$(($(multi $arg[i]) + 1))
        echo $(($RES + 1))
    done
}

f "$@"
```

And get 2 2 2 2 result.

When I use `echo` selfcheck in `multi()`

```
#!/bin/bash
function multi {
    local ax=$1
    echo $ax
    local result=$(($ax + $ax))
    return $result
}

function f {
    local arg="$@"
    for i in ${arg[@]}; do
        RES=$(($(multi $arg[i]) + 1))
        echo $(($RES + 1))
    done
}

f "$@"
```

It prints 3 3 3 3!
**Magic!**

When I change `echo $ax` to `echo "HERE"` it prints 2 2 2 2 and didn't print "HERE" :D.

I think, `multi()` fucntion for some reason takes `$1` from argc, when I'm executing a file in shell and not from `f()`

Comment: `local arg=( "$@" )` should work! Positional arguments need to be stored and processed in a context of an array

Comment: `How to pass an argument to Bash fucntion` don't you want to ask instead what is happening in your code?

Comment: better debugging can be achieved with `set -x` (`set +x` to disable) AND `PS4='${LINENO}'`. Good luck.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command substitution `$(...)` is replaced by the *output* of the execution of the commands inside. `return` sets the *exit status* of a function, does not output anything. Exit status and output on standard output are unrelated.

In the first example there is no `echo` in the multi function, so `$(multi...)` becomes nothing. Then `RES=$(( $(multi ...) + 1))` becomes `RES=$((   + 1))` becomes `RES=1`. So `echo $(($RES + 1))` becomes `echo 2`.

In both examples, `arg="$@"` sets `arg` to a *single* string with arguments separated by spaces. `arg` is not an array and `arg="1 2 3 4"`. The call `multi $arg[i]` is expanded into `multi 1 2 3 4[i]` and executes function `multi` with 4 arguments.

In the second example, `ax` is set to the first argument, so `ax=1` and `echo $ax` *outputs* `1`, so `RES=$(($(multi $arg[i]) + 1))` becomes `RES=$(($(multi 1 2 3 4[i]) + 1))` which becomes `RES=$(( 1 + 1))`, so finally `echo $(($RES + 1))` outputs `3`.

There are numerous problems with the code, like:

- joining arguments with `"$@"`, which in the context used is equal to `"$*"`
- accessing a normal variable `arg="$@"` as an array `${arg[@]}`
- missing quotes
- the `$arg[i]` is odd, I could guess the intention was to `${arg[i]}`, but
- when iterating an array `for i in "${arg[@]}"` `i` is set to the *value* of the element, not an index, so `${arg[i]}` wouldn't work.
- also, do not use `$` inside arithmetic expression `$((` , just `$((RES + 1))`

Several of these problems can be identified with shellcheck. Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck. Additionally, consider researching how to debug Bash scripts, in particular `set -x`.

> How to pass an argument to Bash fucntion

To answer your question, to pass an argument to a Bash function, add the argument after the function. Remember about word splitting expansion splitting unquoted variable expansion into numerous arguments on white spaces and about special cases like `"$@"`.